# NavMeshAgent fails to find paths in certain areas in NavMesh

Tags: unity, path-finding

I've been using Unity for about 2 days, and I have a scene with a navmesh. I can click on the NavMesh and get the NavMeshAgents to move to that position most of the time. However, there is a region of the NavMesh where it fails to generate a path to. I technically have two NavMeshes, because I have two different sized NavMeshAgents, but both fail in the same region. Since I'm very new to Unity, I don't know how to diagnose this, much less fix it. How should I go about learning more about this problem?

I can path through the affected area, as long as the destination point is on the other side of it. Also, when I put a cube in the middle of the affected area and rebake the NavMesh, the problem area moves to a new location, so it must have something to do with the geometry.

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to recreate this problem in a new empty scene? Show us a picture of the simplest scene geometry that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DMGregory I can no longer reproduce the issue. It seemed to go away after reducing both the Tile Size and Voxel Size for each NavMesh. I had a troublesome ramp made from a rotated cube, but when I replaced it with 2 planes, the problems went away. Still don't know what was causing the original problem, but at least it looks like its fixed for now.